# Getting concurrent multiple api calls hits to the backend server in redux saga with apisauce

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, redux-saga

We are using [ignite](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) boilerplate and [apisuace](https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce) for my application. There is a weird problem where some of the POST api's are hitting multiple times to the backend server which chokes the server and makes the server down. Has anyone faced this problem?

Backend server gets more than 500 concurrent requests within a second. And this behavior intermittent.

**indexsaga.js**

```
import { takeLatest, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";
import API from "../Services/Api";
import FixtureAPI from "../Services/FixtureApi";
/* ------------- Types ------------- */
import { LoginTypes } from "../Redux/LoginRedux";


/* ------------- Sagas ------------- */

import {
    loginWithOther,
} from "./LoginSaga";

/* ------------- API ------------- */

// The API we use is only used from Sagas, so we create it here and pass along
// to the sagas which need it.
const api = DebugConfig.useFixtures ? FixtureAPI : API.create();

/* ------------- Connect Types To Sagas ------------- */

export default function* root() {
    yield [// some sagas receive extra parameters in addition to an action
        takeLatest(LoginTypes.USER_REQUEST, loginWithOther, api),
    ];
}
```

**LoginSaga.js**

```
import { call, put, all, fork, select } from "redux-saga/effects";
import LoginActions from "../Redux/LoginRedux";

export function* loginWithOther(api, action) {
    const { email, password, navigation } = action;
    let payload = {
        user_id: email,
        password: password,
    };
    const response = yield call(api.loginWithEmail, payload);
    if (response.ok) {
            yield put(LoginActions.userSuccess(response));
        } else {
            yield put(LoginActions.userFailure());
        }
    } else {
        yield put(LoginActions.userFailure());
    }
}
```

**Loginredux.js**

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    userRequest: ['email', 'password'],
    userSuccess: ['data'],
    userFailure: null
})

export const LoginTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
    fetching: false,
    login_error: false,
    data:null
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */


export const request = (state, action) => {
    return state.merge({ fetching: true, login_error: false })
}

export const success = (state, action) => {
    const { data } = action
    return state.merge({
        fetching: false,
        login_error: false,
        data: data
    })
}

export const userFailure = (state) =>
    state.merge({ fetching: false, login_error: true })



/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {

    [Types.USER_REQUEST]: request,
    [Types.USER_SUCCESS]: success,
    [Types.USER_FAILURE]: userFailure
})
```

**Api.js**

```
// a library to wrap and simplify api calls
import apisauce from "apisauce";

const create = (baseURL = Config.API_URL) => {
    // ------
    // STEP 1
    // ------
    //
    // Create and configure an apisauce-based api object.
    //
    const api = apisauce.create({
        // base URL is read from the "constructor"
        baseURL,
        // here are some default headers
        headers: {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"
            // 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
        },
        // 10 second timeout...
        timeout: 20000
    });


    const URL_STRINGS = {
        LOGIN_WITH_OTHER_EMAIL: "/api/v1/login/email",
    }

    const loginWithEmail = obj => {
        return api.post(URL_STRINGS.LOGIN_WITH_OTHER_EMAIL, obj);
    };


    return {
        loginWithEmail,
    }
};

// let's return back our create method as the default.
export default {
    create
};
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import LoginActions from '../Redux/LoginRedux'
class LoginScreen extends Component {

    render(){
        <View>
            <Text>Login</Text>
        </View>
    }

    onLoginClick(){
        this.props.loginWithEmail("exampleemail@example.com","123456")
Ï
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loginWithEmail: (email, password) =>
            dispatch(LoginActions.userRequest(email, password))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with you Saga implementation of watcher and worker ? and also the action you are dispatching ?

Comment: @suraj updated with code

Comment: where from `LoginTypes.USER_REQUEST` this is being swapned ? Also, i suspect may be the root saga is not having all effect with it. I am not confirmed with that but you should give it a try by writing `yield all([...])` instead of  `yield [... ]`

Comment: @surajmalviya I have added LoginScren.js in which I call USER_REQUEST. Did you face this multiple API hitting issue from your code ?.  I just want to know  if someone is also facing this kind of issue

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that might be causing this. Try debugging it. One gotcha: `takeLatest()` allows new requests while old ones are still executing. Make sure you block "Login" button when a login request is in progress, or users will click the button and make concurrent requests.

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev yes we are . disabling all the buttons once the action is dispatched, but I guess thats not the issue, we are getting more than 500 request within a second, user cannot do this.